# Android Log data

Tags: android

I'am using log to store all the transfer. How can I check the logged data?

```
Log.i("login", "recevied " + getResponse(response.getEntity()));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using eclipse, go to *Window -> Open view -> Other* and select *Logcat*. It will give you a user interface where you can see all the logs generated by the handset or the emulator.

If you are not using Eclipse, you can use `adb logcat` from the command line.

Answer (score 2):

use the [Dalvik Debug Monitor](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/ddms.html)

> DDMS ships in the tools/ directory of the SDK. Enter this directory from a terminal/console and type ddms (or ./ddms on Mac/Linux) to run it.

or, if you are using Eclipse, you can add the Android "LogCat" view to your workspace.

Answer (score 1):

Check [logcat](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debug-tasks.html). If you're debugging under Eclipse, a logcat view is included in the debug perspective.